# how to allow only one line in rich text box

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF (C#).

I want the user to be able to only type one line in a rich text box (can't press enter key).
Could anyone tell me how can I set up this kind of rich text box property?

Answer (score 6):

Set its `AcceptsReturn` property/attribute to `false`.

Comment: Note that this won't block pasting text with newlines.

Comment: (.NET 5, 2022 !) and that is still the case.. also the Copy from the end of the richedit seems to *include* a newline, which is not handy when pasting to append to the richtedit !